# C:out statement with <c:if condition in jstl

Tags: jsp

I am new to jsp,Please guide me through this.
I have a jsp page,where I have one table where all the values except one column is fetching from DB.In one column I need to give if condition with ,please tell me how to do this..

```
<c:if test="${create==0 and secnbr eq null)"
<c:out value="${source}" default="name"
</c:if>
<c:if test ="${create==0 and secnbr ne null)"
```

Comment: Please, provide us what are you putting in the request, what you want to achieve by if condition and what are your problems

Comment: If the code you have provided is your actual code, then you are missing `>` for `<c:if>` tag in `<c:if test="${create==0 and secnbr eq null)"` and in `<c:if test ="${create==0 and secnbr ne null)"`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work ?

```
<td>
    <c:if test="${create==0 and secnbr eq null)">
        <c:out value="${source}" default="name">
    </c:if>
</td>
```